# Sumar día extra

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta sentencia:

```
SELECT u.name, (u.dias_disponibles + COALESCE(dias_extra,0)) as dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados
FROM (

     select u.name, u.dias_disponibles
          , sum( case when s.fk_motivo = 1
                        OR s.fk_motivo = 3) 
                then  dias_disfrutados else 0 end ) as dias_disfrutados
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 4
                then dias_disfrutados else 0 end )  as dias_baja
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 2
                then dias_disfrutados else 0 end )  as dias_extra

      FROM sec_users u 
      left join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
      group by u.name ) u
```

Y estas dos tablas

```
sec_users:

    pk_user   name    dias_disponibles
    ========  =====   ==================
    1         Usuario         24

solicitud:

    pk_solicitud    fk_empleado    dias_disfrutados    motivo
    ============    ============   =================  ==========
    1                    1                 10            1
```

Bueno, esta sentencia crea un pequeño informe, mi problema es que, como se ve al principio `dias_extra`, se suma a `dias_disponibles`, eso lo hace bien. El problema es que no cambia los `dias_libres` o `dias_disfrutados`. Donde está el problema??

Por ejemplo: un usuario tiene `24 dias_disponible`s y pide `10 dias_disfrutados`. El resultado será `24-10 = 14 dias_libres`.

Si el usuario solicita `1 dias_extra`, este día debe agregarse a `dias_disponibles`:

```
24 + 1 = 25
```

Y en este caso, también debe modificar `dias_libres` y `dias_disfrutados`, pero no es así.

Cuando el usuario solicita `10 dias_disfrutados`:

```
name    dias_disponibles   dias_libres    dias_disfrutados
======  ================   ============   ================
Usuario      24                 14               10
```

Cuando el usuario pide `1 dias_extra`

```
name    dias_disponibles   dias_libres    dias_disfrutados
======  ================   ============   ================
Usuario      25                 15               10
```

Pero esta última tabla no la hace bien, no suma el día extra

Comment: Dices que "esta última tabla no la hace bien, no suma el día extra". ¿Donde debería sumar el día extra? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado en este caso?

Comment: @MarcosCrispino De los dos ultimos ejemplos que he puesto, la primera tabla te dice el resultado cuando un usuario pide 10 dias de vacaciones. La segunda tabla es el resultado que debería ser cuando el usuario pide 1 dia extra, pero no me da ese resultado. El resultado que me da a mi es de 25 dias_disponibles pero 14 dias_libres y 10 dias_disfrutados

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que planteas: *Cuando el usuario pide `1` `dias_extra`*... precisamente **¿cuándo lo pide?**, parece como si lo pidiera en otro momento, luego de que la consulta se ha ejecutado, por lo tanto no se puede ver reflejado en el resultado...

Comment: A ver, por ejemplo, usuario1 pide un día extra, mi intención es que ese día extra se sume a los días disponibles que tiene el usuario en la tabla de  `sec_users`, osea si pide 1 dia, pues en vez de 24, debería salir 25

Comment: @A.Cedano mira este enlace, te he creado ahí la base de datos y le he puesto la sentencia. Al usuario 'Alvaro', le he puesto 24 dias disponibles. Está bien pero prueba con esta sentencia: select dias_disponibles from sec_users where name = 'Alvaro' [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752af2/1]

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que cuando el usuario pide un día extra, el resultado esperado es:

```
name    dias_disponibles   dias_libres    dias_disfrutados
======  ================   ============   ================
Usuario      25                 15               10
```

Entonces lo que falta a la consulta es que agregues el día extra a los `dias_libres`:

```
SELECT u.name,
       (u.dias_disponibles + COALESCE(dias_extra,0)) as dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles + COALESCE(dias_extra,0) - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados
FROM (
    select u.name, u.dias_disponibles
      , sum( case when s.fk_estado <> 2 
            and (s.fk_motivo = 1
                    OR s.fk_motivo = 3) 
            then  N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end ) as dias_disfrutados
      , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 4
            then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as dias_baja
      , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 2
            then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as dias_extra
  FROM sec_users u 
  left join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
  group by u.name ) u
```

Comment: Si! Precisamente eso he hecho y en principio está bien. Pero cuando inicio la consulta para ver los días disponibles de cada usuario, por ejemplo de usuario1, me sale 24 y me debería salir 25

Comment: Solo me lo ha sumado al informe pero no en la tabla de usuarios

Comment: Se entiende? Cuando el usuario pide 1 día extra, ese día se debe sumar a los `dias_disponibles` de la tabla de `sec_users`

Comment: No, no se entiende... Ya está "sumado" a la tabla `sec_users`, solo que con FK_Motivo = 2. Si los días disponibles se componen de los días disponibles de base (por decirlo de alguna forma) más los días extra, entonces las consultas que quieran obtener los días disponibles no tienen más opción que hacer la suma.

Comment: Marcos mira este enlace, te he creado ahí la base de datos y le he puesto la sentencia que me has mandado. Al usuario 'Alvaro', le he puesto 24 dias disponibles. Está bien pero prueba con esta sentencia: 

select dias_disponibles
  from sec_users
  where name = 'Alvaro'
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752af2/1]

Comment: Entenderás lo que yo quiero